# structured streaming write to different parquet folders

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet, spark-structured-streaming

I am using spark structured streaming to read events from a kafka topic and process it and write to parquet. I have to write the output to different folders based on the key i get in the event.I tried with the structured streaming examples always point to a specific folder .Do i need to start a stream for each folder?

`df.writeStream.format("parquet").option("path", "path/to/destination/dir").start()`

Comment: You could partition a parent directory based on a key, which would make a folder for each value

Comment: thanks but the key is coming in the message but for writing to parquet  i need to specify it while the time of writeStream.start. but actual data is coming later. then how do i specify it in the partition?

Comment: like  can i read the key from the datafame and use the value in the partition.  dataframe.writeStream.format("parquet")
             .option("path",path)  but its not working

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this  by creating multiple writeStreams each specific to a table

for details pl refer to the [structured streaming different schema in nested json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51826841/structured-streaming-different-schema-in-nested-json)

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreachBatch

```
streamingDF.writeStream.foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
  batchDF.persist()
  batchDF.write.format(...).save(...)  // location 1
  batchDF.write.format(...).save(...)  // location 2
  batchDF.unpersist()
}
```

for more information you can refer [spark documenation foreach and foreachBatch](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch)